# Does j2objc support guava?

Tags: java, objective-c, guava

I'm trying to use j2objc to translate some java code. My code uses google Guava library, when I try to import any class

```
import com.google.common.collect.Maps;
```

I get an error message saying it cannot be resolved.

```
The import com.google.common cannot be resolved
```

Is there something special which needs to be done to enable Guava support in j2objc converter?

Answer (score 3):

A translation of Guava is not currently part of the j2objc distribution, though there are plans to include a big subset of that library (including Maps).  What projects do today is download the Guava source, then translate the classes they want to use.

One problem with this approach is determining the closure of dependent classes; i.e., what Guava classes does Maps depend on, and what are the dependencies of those classes, and so on.  We let javac determine that:

```
$ javac -d /tmp/guava -sourcepath <guava-source-paths> com.google.common.collect.Maps
$ cd /tmp/guava

$ find com -name '*.class' > /tmp/all-classes.list  # list all classes
$ fgrep -v '$' < /tmp/all-classes.list > /tmp/classes.list # get rid of inner classes
$ sed -s '/class$/java/' < /tmp/classes.list > /tmp/source-files
```

A tool that determines the source file list is planned for the next release.